# where to store/keep configuration data for an Java Enterprise application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web

> What is the best way to store parameters and data for an EE7 application. I have to provide the web applications with information like a  member fee or similar data  (which may/can be altered several times in a year). The owner of the application should also have a central place where these data are stored  and an application to change them.
>   Thanks  in advance for any input

Franz

Comment: In the database. What you describe is just data.

Answer (score 1):

This is one question we are currently struggling with as we re-architect some of our back-end systems here, and I do agree with the comment from @JB Nizet that it should be stored on *the database*, however I will try to add some additional considerations and options to help you make the decision that is right for you. The right option will depend on a few factors though.

If you are **delivering source code and automation** to build and deploy your software, the configuration can be stored in a source code repository (i.e. as YAML or XML) and bundled with your deployable during the build process. This is a bit archaic but certainly widely adopted practice and works well, for the most part.

If you are delivering deployable binaries, you have a couple of options.

First one is to have a **predetermined place in the file system** where your application will look for an "override" configuration file (i.e. home directory of the user used to run your application server). This way you can have your binary deployable file completely separate from your configuration, but you will still need to build some sort of automation and version control for that configuration file so that your customer can roll back versions if/when necessary. This can also be one or many configuration files (i.e. separate files for your app server, vs. the application itself).

The option we are contemplating currently is having a configuration database where all of our applications can query for their own configuration. This can either be a very simple or complex solution depending on your particular needs - for us these are internal applications and we manage the entire lifecycles ourselves, but we have a need to have a central repository since we have tens of services and applications running with a good number of common configuration keys, and updating these keys independently can be error prone.

We are looking at a few different solutions, but I would certainly not store the configuration in our main database as: 1) I don't think SQL is best repository for configuration, 2) I believe we can get better performance from NoSQL databases which can be critical if you need to load some of those configuration keys for every request.

MongoDB and CouchDB both come to mind as good candidates for storing the our configuration keys if you need clearly defined hierarchy for you options, whereas Redis or Memcached are great options if you just need a key-value storage for your configuration (faster than document based too). We will also likely build a small app to help up configure and version the configuration and push changes to existing/active servers, but we haven't spec'd out all the requirements for that.

There are also some OSS solutions that may work for you, although some of them add too much complexity for what we are trying to achieve at this point. If you are using springframework, take a look at the [Spring Cloud Config Project](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html), it is very interesting and worth looking into.

This is a very interesting discussion and I am very willing to continue it if you have more questions on how to achieve distributed configurations. Food for thought, here are some of my personal must haves and nice to haves for our new configuration architecture design:

- Global configuration per environment (dev,staging,prod)
- App specific configuration per environment (dev,staging,prod)
- Auto-discovery (auto environment selection depending on requestor)
- Access control and versioning
- Ability to push updates live to different services

Answer (score 0):

Roger,thanks a lot. Do you have an example for the version predetermined place in the file system"predetermined place in the file system"? Does it make sense to use a singleton  which reads the configuration file (using Startup annotation) and provides then the configuration data?  But this does not support a dynamic solution.kind regards Franz

Comment: One of the options we are toying with right now is have our chef scripts drop a JSON file on the home directory for the Tomcat user and have our application override the internal configuration with the options from that file. Not super elegant, but would do the job.